# How to remove lines letters repeated more than N times in any position?

Tags: text, awk, sed, line

What way is it possible to leave or remove lines which contain letters repeated more than N times in any position?
I need to delete lines where X or Y repeats  4 and more times in any position. For example:

```
XAABCCC
XABXXBA
BCXXXCX
AXXXXCA
```

Output should be:

```
XAABCCC
XABXXBA
```

Searching in Internet for SED or AWK using and reading tutorials haven't helped me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question and example are unclear. Do you mean 1) lines containing 4 Xs or 4 Ys, or 2) lines containing 4 Xs-or-Ys, or 3) something else? Updated your sample input/output to include a line with 4 Ys and a line with 2 Xs and 2 Ys.

Comment: I meant 2) lines containing 4 Xs-or-Ys.

Answer (score 1):

Using grep:

```
~$ grep -Ev "(X.*){4,}" myfile
XAABCCC
XABXXBA
```

You search for `X` with possibly something after, 4 times. The `-v` negates the match.

Answer (score 1):

For any character instead of just X:

```
grep -Ev "(.)(.*\1){3,}" input
```

For uppercase letters only:

```
grep -Ev "([A-Z])(.*\1){3,}" input
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative with `sed`:

```
sed -n 'h;s/[^X]//g;/XXXX/{x;p}' file
```

Explanation:

```
h            - Put current line into hold buffer
s/[^X]//g    - Replace all non X chars ...
/XXXX/{x;p}  - ... and check if the line holds 4 or more X
               If yes, then get back the original line from 
               hold buffer -> x and print the line -> p
```

Answer (score 1):

This MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat file
XAABCCC
XABXXBA
BCXXXCX
AXXXXCA
BCXYXCY
BCYYYCY
XCYXYCY

$ awk 'gsub(/[XY]/,"&")>=4' file
BCXXXCX
AXXXXCA
BCXYXCY
BCYYYCY
XCYXYCY
```

If not then edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$ sed '/\(X.*\)\{4\}/d' input
XAABCCC
XABXXBA
```

**OR**

```
$ awk '/(X.*){4}/' input
BCXXXCX
AXXXXCA
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/X/&/4;T;d' file
```

If you can replace 4 `X`'s by themselves then delete the line.

N.B. Is the reverse of the `t` command, which apon a successful substitution branches. Here `T` bails out on an unsuccessful substitution which prints the line.